# Kinect V1 not connecting to Kinect Studio v1.8.0

Tags: 3d, processing, kinect, point-clouds, truedepth-camera

I am currently facing an issue with Kinect V1 and Kinect Studio v1.8.0. Despite attempting to connect, I encounter the following error message: "Please launch a Kinect-enabled app and then press the refresh button." I have attached a screenshot for reference.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Attempted to connect with Kinect Studio v1.8.0.
Tried using a Kinect-enabled software (3D scan) but encountered the same issue.
Additional Information:

I am using Kinect V1.
The error persists even with a Kinect-enabled application.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utdRC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open kinect for windows 1.8 SDK. Then open the Kinect developer toolkit 1.8. Run a sample in the developer toolkit. Then click "Refresh" button in that message box in the Kinect studio v1.8. It'll connect.